# PHP - How to check if array contains a value by index?

Tags: php, arrays

Example:
`$array = ['name', 'address'];`

It contains `$array[0]` and `$array[1]` only.

If i try `$array[2]` i should receive an error.

So, i want to avoid these errors by checking it in a if statement. How can i check if an array contains a value in certain index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the isset function:

```
if(isset($array[2])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The second way to make it work is check how big is an array:

`if(count($array) >= 3) { ... } // three or more elements: 0, 1, 2...`